# Will MainApplication always run after updating the app, even if the user does not open it?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-lifecycle

My app has some widgets which, in the new version of the app, require some additional data. I get this data in `MainApplication.java`, but I am worried that when the users update, `MainApplication` will not run automatically if they don't manually open the app. However, since the widgets will already be on the homescreen, and since this data will be unavailable, widgets will crash.

Are my fears realistic or will `MainApplication` ALWAYS run first (also before `AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` is called), even after the app is automatically updated and the user does not it at all?

Comment: Did you try setting logs?

Comment: have you tested it yet on device above oreo ? device with customized OS , you should use service and check if the app is removed from tasks etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is started, the constructor of your `Application` implementation is called first and the `Application::onCreate()` method is called right after. I'm assuming that's what you are asking when you say "will `MainApplication` always run first?". Take a look at what the docs say about `Application::onCreate()` (taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate())):

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

Also, this method won't be called when your app is updating and, as far as I know, it won't be called when your app finishes updating.

The `AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` method, on the other hand, is called after the app is reinstalled. The code to upgrade your widgets should be placed inside it, so it will be executed after your app's upgrade.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        //Update your widgets here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed! I have implemented "upgrade" mechanism in the `onUpdate()` now.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Cheers!